# Is it really necessary to provide all the different app icon sizes for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, image, vector-graphics

I'm tempted to provide the highest resolution icon and let iOS scale it down as necessary. Is this a bad idea, and (if so) why?

Comment: I don't think the app store will accept a binary missing required icons.

Comment: If you have a vector PSD and drag it into XCode as the app icon, it will automatically extract all the right sizes for you. If you have a 1024x1024 PSD, then there are websites that will create all the right sizes for you.

Comment: Xcode won't even validate your app anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it might be bad idea. If your icon art was produced using a *[vector image editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics_editor#Vector_editors_versus_bitmap_editors)* (e.g., Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop *with* vector primitives, Sketch, etc) you best bet is to export *all* required resolutions yourself. In doing so, you will guarantee the best possible output for each resolution.

Keep in mind that exporting a *single* high resolution image and *then* resizing, for each required resolution, using a bitmap editor (e.g., macOS Preview) won't produce the same results.

**PS**. As already pointed out, I'm not sure your binary will even be accepted by Apple if missing icon data :-(

Answer (score 2):

you'll definitely want to produce files of various sizes as required by xCode. You want to make sure that the file presented when the app runs is of a high quality.

There are tools out there that will automatically create all the sizes you need for your app icon. Here is a link to the site that I use: https://makeappicon.com/

Hope that helps!